# How to configure checkstyle confuguration for Ant in Hudson?

Tags: ant, hudson, checkstyle

How can I configure checkstyle (in Ant nt Maven) task? I tried little bit but I didn't get the reports properly. Here's my ant script.

```
<target name="checkStyle">
    <taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties">
        <classpath refid="compile.class.pathtest"/>
    </taskdef>

    <checkstyle config="${source.code.dir}/config/sun_checks.xml">
        <fileset dir="${base.working.dir}/JavaFolder">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
        <formatter type="plain"/>
        <formatter type="xml" toFile="checkstyle-result.xml"/>
    </checkstyle>
</target>

<path id="compile.class.pathtest">
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/checkstyle-5.5-all.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/checkstyle-5.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/pmd-3.9.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/asm-3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/backport-util-concurrent-2.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/jaxen-1.1-beta-10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${checkstyle.dir}/saxpath-1.0-FCS.jar"/>
</path>
```

What's that sun_checks.xml file? I have downloaded and kept in the above mentioned folder. While running the build, it shows some warnings and errors. Later, it shows like this.

BUILD FAILED

C:\server\build.xml:9725: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\server\build.xml:3838: Got 56 errors and 27599 warnings.

Can you please guide me how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `sun_checks.xml` file contains the [checkstyle configurations](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html), i.e. all rules that should be applied when evaluating your source code.

Your build failes, because checkstyle found error.

You can set the [failOnViolation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html) property to false to avoid this. This property defaults to true, when it is not set.

```
<checkstyle config="${source.code.dir}/config/sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
    <fileset dir="${base.working.dir}/JavaFolder">
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    <formatter type="plain"/>
    <formatter type="xml" toFile="checkstyle-result.xml"/>
</checkstyle>
```

Comment: Where to set these props `source.code.dir` & `base.working.dir` ?